# How to check whether files in one Amazon S3 bucket in one account are same as files in an Amazon S3 bucket from another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have 2 AWS accounts, each containing an Amazon S3 bucket with files in them. There are many files (1000+) in both of them and I want a way of confirming which files are present in both buckets, and what files each has that the other one doesn't. Is there an automated way to do this, perhaps via AWS CLI or a functionality in the console?

Comment: [`aws s3 sync`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) with `--dryrun`

Comment: `aws s3 sycn` with `--dryrun` + cross account access to one of the buckets, example for the policy [https://serverfault.com/a/974024/773689](https://serverfault.com/a/974024/773689). Although, I'm not sure fi dryrun request `PutObject`.